# Move large files from one Google account to another?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

I have reached the space limit of my primary Gmail (Google) account, meaning soon I won't be able to send emails.

How can I move large files from this primary Google account to a secondary one to free up some space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could share the files and then copy them on the new drive. If there are many files, you can use colab to automate it: [like in this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120362/how-to-copy-a-shared-folder-into-my-own-google-drive)